# How to combine multiple point cloud of same object hand scan

Tags: c++, glsl, qtopengl

I'm working on a school project and one of the things i have to do is to combine multiple scans of the same object. These scans or .obj files and i want to combine them to obtain a better scan object.

I search solutions on the internet but i don't find any acceptable solution, so if someone just have an idea or a track to follow, i will appreciate it.

If you have any question about my problem ask me, maybe my english is not correct, i'm French.

Thank's !

Answer (score 1):

You have a collection of N point clouds, representing the same object, possibly all in a different space (given by a transformation matrix), and you want to combine them into only one point cloud. Is that correct?

I may miss the point, because the only method I can think of is quite simple. So correct me if I'm wrong.

Put all the point clouds into the same space. Now, all your points are in the same space and merging your transformed point clouds is trivial.

You might want to remove duplicate points though, since they could be annoying for algorithms using neighbourhood. To do so, you can use a kdtree and make a radius search around each point with a very small radius to detect clusters: keep only one point for each cluster found. With the scan resolution, you could have a good guess of what is the typical distance `d` between two adjacent points. Otherwise, you could estimate it by computing the average distance between a point and its closest / second closest point, for each transformed point cloud. Now, a "small radius" is a small portion of this typical distance `d`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) i will try this today and come back later but i think a kdtree is a good solution.